# No me corre phpMyAdmin con symfony, es posible configurarlo?

Tags: phpmyadmin, symfony3

Actualmente necesito el **phpMyAdmin** para instalar el **Wordpress**, tengo instalado el **symfony** pero al querer ejecutar desde la web el **phpMyAdmin** desde la url *localhost/phpMyAdmin/* me da el siguiente error:

> Oops! An Error Occurred The server returned a "404 Not Found".
>   Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this
>   error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any
>   inconvenience caused.

Comment: ¿Estás intentando acceder así: `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` ruta completa, http incluido y todo en minúscula? Por favor comenta el sistema operativo que estás usando.

Comment: hola, gracias por responder, si ruta completa, y estoy usando windows 7 64bits

Comment: otra cosa estoy usando appserv ese es el paquete

Comment: ¿Esto tampoco funciona? `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin` O bien esto: `http://127.0.0.1:81/phpmyadmin`

Comment: Hola amigo, tampoco la primera opcion da el mismo error, la segunda opcion dice Firefox no puede establecer una conexión con el servidor en 127.0.0.1:81.

Comment: ¿Qué en el archivo `C:\Windows\System64\drivers\etc\hosts`?

Comment: la direccion que encontré es esta C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc el archivo host tiene lo siguiente:     (ademas de todo el texto explicativo)                                                            
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1             localhost

Comment: ¿Qué abre si pones solamente `http://localhost/`?

Comment: Yo quitaría los dos últimos signos de # del archivo hosts y guardaría los cambios. Los símbolos ponen ambas líneas como "comentadas", o sea, las anulan e indican que en tu equipo localhost está desactivado ya que la resolución de nombres será manejada por Windows.

Comment: la solucion temporal que encontré fue cambiar los directorios de symfony en el archivo httpd.conf del apache, dentro de la carpeta apache/conf y me funciona perfectamente aunque si quiero volver al symfony tengo que volver a activarlos ._.                           (DocumentRoot "C:/AppServ/www"
#DocumentRoot C:/AppServ/symfony/project/web
#<Directory C:/AppServ/symfony/project/web>
<Directory "C:/AppServ/www">)